# what kind of event type is the event on the onInputChange props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to use React.ChangeEvent on the mui v4 autocomplete component since I don't want to go with any.
how ever it is throwing an error that the current event is not compatible.

```js
  const handle = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>, currentValue: string, reason: string) => {
  console.log(e,currentValue,reason)
  }

<Autocomplete onInputChange={handle}/>
```

Comment: "it is throwing an error that the current event is not compatible." That error should tell you what your current type is not compatible with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TypeScript's [inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) capabilities along with some [type utilities](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) to derive the function signature that you're asking about.

Here's an example using a type annotation on a handler function:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzjAnmApnAwgCwIYB2A5ugKIBu6B8AvnAGZQQhwDkU6eAxjKwNwAoUJFiIBcOAEEArjAhdmYADboY6ADTjkaTDLkLwKtQEkCYWbkIkASpwDOEApokuA9K4B6AfgF1GzNgABEDw1KGA8JQBaaWBXJTwAI34BAVQMOAB5AlNzGEtiTABeOAAFPCg8EFV0KDsAHnT0CHopWXlFI3QAPgBtAAYAXV7WR1yLfELWQcEBBQI7eEmAExVx-MmSAC4snLMJq2K4AAp0Smp1OHJI6Q04DjwHAgBKOCLusQkzqhhBd29UhJrkpbn9PD4tA8nmCAVp3HAAJoQaRQODCFTVaihYCOOA4WroXyCIA)

```ts
import { type ChangeEvent } from 'react';
import {
  Autocomplete,
  type AutocompleteInputChangeReason,
     //^? (alias) type AutocompleteInputChangeReason = "input" | "reset" | "clear"
} from '@material-ui/lab';

type OnInputChange = Parameters<typeof Autocomplete>[0]['onInputChange'];

const handleInputChange: OnInputChange = (event, value, reason) => {
  event;
//^? (parameter) event: ChangeEvent<{}>

  value;
//^? (parameter) value: string

  reason;
//^? (parameter) reason: AutocompleteInputChangeReason

  // Your implementation here
};
```

Note that the `Autocomplete` component function is generic, but — in my testing — no variation in supplied generic types seems to affect the generic type used for the inner `ChangeEvent` parameter, and the result is always `ChangeEvent<{}>`.

The type for `ChangeEvent` (which comes from React) is `ChangeEvent<T = Element>`, so if you are targeting a specific element, you can use the information above to write your own compatible function signature manually, but using the specific element type that is most appropriate for your scenario.

Comment: That was exactly the missing puzzle.

Answer (score -1):

> #### Signature:
>
> `function(event: object, value: string, reason: string) => void`
> *event:* The event source of the callback.
> *value:* The new value of the text input.
> *reason:* Can be: `"input"` (user input), `"reset"` (programmatic change), `"clear"`.

[MUI documentation for Autocomplete API](https://v4.mui.com/api/autocomplete/)